# Cancel and OK buttons are not coming in emulator

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to make an image slider app. image sliding is done.But
after image view i want to add two button like "OK" and "Cancel". But
these two buttons are not coming in emulator.
My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/black">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextViewTopTitle" android:text="@string/app_logo_top" android:textColor="@color/logo_color" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:gravity="top|center" android:textSize="@dimen/logo_size"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Left" android:contentDescription="@string/desc" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></ImageView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/cancell" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center|left" android:text="@string/can" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your code, and tell us what you *specifically* have problems with.

Comment: I am trying to add "OK" and "Edit" buttons after IMAGEVIEW. But it is not appearing in th emmulator when i am running the code...